# perl find and replace

Tags: linux, perl

What is the perl command line on linux to find and replace a text.I want to search

```
  <?php echo "Testing"; ?>
```

I want to replace above with `<?php echo "Production"; ?>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
perl -pi -we's/\Q<?php echo "Testing"; ?>/<?php echo "Production"; ?>/g' file ...
```

Comment: `\Q` need not be terminated with `\E`?

Comment: @PP `\Q` is documented as “quote (disable) pattern metacharacters till `\E`,” so in the absence of `\E`, the effect of `\Q` continues through the end of the pattern.